# Find smallest value greater than each element in list

Tags: r

Given a vector `lookup` and an ordered vector `ref`, I would like a vector `result` where `result[i]` is equal to the index of the smallest element in `ref` such that `lookup[i] > ref[result[i]`

For example:

```
ref <- c(1,5,10,15)
lookup <- c(2.3,10.5, 17,2,6)

result: 1,3,4,1,2
```

How can I do this in R without using a for loop?

Comment: `findInterval(lookup, ref)`.

Comment: @psidom That is exactly it.  Will you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ref` vector is ordered, you can use `findInterval` to *find the interval Numbers or indices* in `ref` for a numeric x:

```
ref <- c(1,5,10,15)
lookup <- c(2.3,10.5,17,2,6)
findInterval(lookup, ref)
# [1] 1 3 4 1 2
```